# MySQL: comma separated string within IN()

Tags: mysql

I've seen a lot of questions with a similar question. However, all the answers  are misleading. Most answers say to use [FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php) and this seems incorrect to my question.

Below query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  data_table 
WHERE field_id IN ('618,622,626,773,776');
```

Would normally just show the first ID row. In this example being '618'

```
id   data 
---  ------
618  ....
```

How would one go about this *without* using any stored procedures or user defined functions? Displaying the following results:

```
id   data 
---  ------
618  ....
622  ....
626  ....
773  ....
776  ....
```

**Note;** '618,622,626,773,776' will always remain as a string. This is the problem here.

Comment: Why is `FIND_IN_SET` "completely incorrect" here? It looks for an entry in a string that contains entries comma-separated. Isn't this exactly what you want? `IN` on the other hand looks for an entry in a data set, but you don't have a data set, you have a string.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET __is__ the correct answer. `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE FIND_IN_SET(field_id, '618,622,626,773,776')`

Comment: A side note: That your query finds the record with field_id 618 is a flaw in the DBMS in my opinion. '618,622,626,773,776' should not be convertable to int, but MySQL simply converts the first substring.

Comment: Hello. Those set of numbers are coming from php?

Comment: Seems like you don't need the quotes, but I'm unclear about your note that it will always be a string. The form `WHERE field_id IN (618,622,626,773,776)` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Most answers say to use FIND_IN_SET and this is completely **incorrect** to my question.

It is **completely correct**. If it didn’t work for you – then you just used it wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(field_id, '618,622,626,773,776')
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I was a bit too forward. But with a better applied example, I see what you mean.